# How do I convert an MMAP file to another file type?

Tags: python, hex, jpeg, mmap

I'm working on some code in python that loads a file (a jpeg) as an MMAP file so it can edit some of the hex data directly.

This is fine, I have no issue with that hat I *am* struggling with is getting that edited MMAP file (which I've saved as the variable "final")  *back* into the JPEG format.

below you can see my code that I use to open and edit the file:

```
import mmap
import io
with open("15.jpg", mode="rb") as file_obj:
     with mmap.mmap(file_obj.fileno(), length=0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as mmap_obj:
      text = mmap_obj.read()
      print(text)

final = str(text).replace(r"\x12",r"\x68")
print()
print(final)
```

if anybody could help me with saving the MMAP file as a JPG or show me other methods of achieving a similar result (editing the hex data and saving the file) I'd  be extremely grateful

Comment: Why are you even bothering with `mmap` if you're just going to `read` the whole thing?

Comment: Don't convert it to `str` - `bytes` instances have their own replace method, do `final = text.replace(b"\x12",b"\x68")`.  Image files are binary data, calling `str()` on them will just produce garbage.